# Copy NLA tracks from one armature to another

Tags: animation, armature, nla-editor

I've been doing my animation on a low poly model. And now I want to transfer the animations to the high-poly model. I'm doing the following steps:
1. Link the high-poly model into a new blend file
2. Link the scene from the animated file
3. copy transforms from the low-poly to high-poly
4. Apply the actions from the low-poly to the high-poly
5. Rebuild the action strip sequnce in the NLA editor for the high-poly model.

It's not hard but it strikes me as common workflow, where you wouldn't necessarily want to animate a high-poly model, so you work with a lower res version. Admittedly, if the model was designed properly it's mesh wouldn't be too high-poly, and would use a subsurf modifier. But alas, I'm not a modeler and this is a model I bought that worked for me.

Is there a way to apply the NLA editor sequence of the low-poly model to the high-poly model in less steps. Almost, like saying replace the low-res model with a high-res model, and it'll just do it.

I'm aware of this: [How can i copy NLA Tracks from one armature to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74183/how-can-i-copy-nla-tracks-from-one-armature-to-another)

But I don't have the cycles (no pun intended) to go down the path of fiddling around with python scripts at this stage of the project.

thanks

Comment: Sounds like writing a python script might be easier than adjusting your files. Ideally you want to setup your files to support hi/lo versions. If you look at the sintel files, both the hi and lo poly meshes are in the same file and use the same armature, the animation files animate the armature and can easily switch between the lo and hi poly mesh.

Comment: both my lo and hi poly meshes use the same armature. But I didn't include them in the same .blend file initially. But I did link them (Ctrl+Alt+O) to the same file. That's how I'm able to transfer the actions to the hi poly mesh. But since I use the NLA editors to combine multiple actions, I had to rebuild it for the hi poly mesh. That's the part I'm wondering if there is a way to share the NLA editor strips between armatures. How did they do it in the sintel files? I have to find those files and take a look.

Comment: In the sintel files two groups are created hi and lo - when you link from an external file you import the group and an empty is created, the dupligroup settings on the empty switch between the two meshes using the same armature and animation data.