# Create NLA transition with Python

Tags: python, nla-editor

Is it possible to create transition between clips with python?

[image: Transition]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of how to do it, using [`bpy.ops.nla.transition_add`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.nla.html#bpy.ops.nla.transition_add)

```py
import bpy

# Generate an override that can be used for this call.
win = bpy.context.window
scr = win.screen
areas  = [area for area in scr.areas if area.type == 'NLA_EDITOR']
regions   = [region for region in areas[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW']
override = { 'area': areas[0], 'region' : regions[0] }

# Replace this line with one that selects the object that has the NLA Tracks
object = bpy.context.active_object

# Replace this line with one that selects the NLA Track you want.
track = object.animation_data.nla_tracks['NLaTrack']

# Replace the next two lines with ones that select the desired strips.
# They must be adjacent.
# No other strips should be selected so you may have to deselect all first.
track.strips[0].select = True
track.strips[1].select = True

# Add the transition, using the override calculated earlier.
bpy.ops.nla.transition_add(override)
```

The key is that you have to select two *adjacent* [NLA strips](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NlaStrip.html) and that the `bpy.ops.nla.transition_add` call needs a [context override](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context).

#### 3.2 Update

Context overrides are deprecated in Blender 3.2 and are scheduled to be removed in Blender 3.3  The replacement is [`temp_override`](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.2/bpy.types.Context.html#bpy.types.Context.temp_override). The manual has examples of how to use the new function.

Comment: Thank you Marty! But is there solution without selection these clips? Something similar to: bpy.types.NlaStrips.new( ... )

I am creating simple addon for duplicate whole NLA from one object to other. I can easily copy all clips with settings, but I don't know how to copy the transitions.

It is releated to this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/163875/1910

Comment: bpy ops tend not to be very flexible and there's really no way to add a transition without knowing where it goes, as far as I know. Unfortunately "where it goes" is between two selected strips. But copying might be a different problem. Maybe ask a separate question about copying between two tracks?

Comment: @Cenda I just added an answer to the other question that should handle your transition case.